# Excel VLOOKUP Query - Matching data from 2 spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

Hoping someone can help, as it is driving me crazy.

I have `Spread sheet 1` with the columns `Product Name` and `Price`, I have `spread sheet 2` with the column `Product Name`.

I need to use the VLOOKUP formula to match the product names and put the prices in `spread sheet 2`.

I keep getting the formula backwards, Can anyone help please?

My current formula in `spread sheet 2` column `B` is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[spreadsheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$215,1,FALSE)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "formula backwards"?

Comment: just that I cant write it

Comment: You mean, you can't enter it? Post formula you're trying to enter.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(A2,'[spreadsheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$215,1,FALSE) in spread sheet 2 coloumn B

Comment: What message do you get? Is it a `,` against `;` problem?

Comment: It returns the product name column instead of the price column

Comment: You must specify col_index_num = 2 instead if 1!

Comment: I tried that just now and it comes up with #REF!

Comment: Ok, let's solve this and stop guessing: what columns are Product name and price? Do you have book opened? Is list sorted?

Comment: OK, thanks. Spread sheet 1 has columns A (Product Name) and column B (Price). Spread sheet 2 has column A (Product Name). I have entered the function in spread sheet 2, in Column B. Both spread sheets are open, list is not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'[spreadsheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for persevering, this now works! Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer `INDEX` and `MATCH`, especially with an unsorted list:

```
=INDEX('[spreadsheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$215,MATCH(A2,'[spreadsheet 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$2:$B$215,0))
```

Comment: I prefer `OFFSET` and `MATCH`.